# Django view skips checking permission classes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I'm trying to filter lists according to:

- the user can work with all of their lists
- the user can use safe methods on public lists

I have this code:

In views.py:

```
class LinkListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,
                  generics.ListAPIView,
                  generics.RetrieveAPIView):
queryset = LinkList.objects.all()
serializer_class = LinkListSerializer
permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrPublic]
```

In permissions.py:

```
class IsOwnerOrPublic(BasePermission):
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return obj.owner == request.user or (
        obj.public and (request.method in SAFE_METHODS))
```

The problem is, I believe the view just skips checking the permission classes and returns all lists, and I am not sure why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only check the `has_object_permission` for requests that work with an object, so for example the `RetrieveAPIView`, not the `ListAPIView`.

You should filter for the latter, so we can make a custom `IsOwnerOrPublicFilterBackend` filter backend:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from rest_framework import filters

class IsOwnerOrPublicFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(Q(owner=request.user) | Q(public=True))
```

and then use that filter as `filter_backend` in the `ModelViewSet`:

```
class LinkListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LinkList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LinkListSerializer
    filter_backends = [IsOwnerOrPublicFilterBackend]
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrPublic]
```